# Update int column in table with incrementing value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi how can i update column with increment values starting with certain value

for example if have table `store` with below sample data

```
ProID ProName
1     Pro1
2     Pro2
3     Pro3
etc ..
```

how can update `ProID` value with starting value for example 10 then increment the rest of values so it will be

```
ProID ProName
10     Pro1
11     Pro2
12     Pro3
etc ..
```

Comment: `update store set ProID = ProID + 9`.  If that doesn't work, please update your question with a better example (before someone provides an answer and such an update invalidates their answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as 
( select prodID, row_number() over (order by prodID) as rn 
  from table 
)
update cte set prodID = rn + 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to provide a more generic answer to this question.  And, I'm going to assume that `ProId` has a `unique` index.  So, the obvious solution:

```
update store
    set ProID = ProID + 9;
```

is not guaranteed to work.  It might generate duplicates (if there is already an id = 10).  And it won't fill in gaps.

Unfortunately, I think you need to do this in two steps (when there is a unique index).  The problem is duplicates as you are updating the table.  If this works, then great:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*, 9 + row_number() over (order by ProId) as new_ProId
      from store
     )
update toupdate
    set ProId = new_ProId;
```

However, you might need to do this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*, 9 + row_number() over (order by ProId) as new_ProId
      from store
     )
update toupdate
    set ProId = - new_ProId;  -- ensure no duplicates by using a negative sign

update store
    set ProId = - ProId;      -- get rid of the negative sign
```

Having said all that, updating the primary key of a table is almost never the right thing to do.  Gaps in the value are generally not a problem.  You can use `row_number()` when you query the table to remove the gaps, if that is necessary for some reason.